# Trouble understanding output from a recursive function.

Tags: java, recursion, void

I'm having trouble understanding what happens to this piece of code when it returns. After it outputs 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 why does it outputs 1 after 0 and not 0 again?

```
public static void a(int b){
    if(b<0)
       return;

    System.out.println(b);

    a(b-1);
    a(b+1); 
}
```

Comment: Pen and paper always helps in such cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this particular example returns a StackOverflowError I don't think that's the kind of answer you're looking for. So pretending that error-causing line wasn't there let me demonstrate what is happening:

```
public static void a(int b){
if(b<0)
   return;

System.out.println(b);

a(b-1);
a(b+1); //assuming this didn't go to infinity
}
```

The method runs exactly like it reads, but you create sub-tasks.

It checks the if statement, then prints the value of b. Then it runs a(b-1) and then runs a(b+1).

You're getting odd results because `then it runs a(b-1)` is actually a series of tasks in and of itself. THAT method does all the things I mentioned before and they will all happen BEFORE the first instance ever reaches a(b+1).

Lets say you called `a(1);`

```
1 is not less than 0
print 1
a(1-1) //which is zero a(0)
//begin sub-task a(0)
  0 is not less than 0
  print 0
  a(0-1) // which is -1
  //begin sub-task a(-1)
    -1 is less than 0 so return
  a(0+1) 
  1 is not less than zero
  print 1
  a(1-1) // which is zero
  zero is not less than zero
  print zero
  a(0-1)
  etc. etc.
```

It may be easier to think of this as

```
public static void a(int b){
if(b<0)
    return;
System.out.println(b);
a(b-1);
System.out.println(b + " is done");
}
```

This does the following with `a(1);`:

```
if(1 < 0) // false
print 1
   begin a(1-1) or a(0)
   if(0 < 0) // false
   print 0
      begin a(0-1) or a(-1)
      if(-1 < 0) //true so return IE go back to the calling method
   print "0 is done"
print "1 is done"
```

Comment: I'm sorry because I'm new to recursion so I'm a little bit confused, but after I put System.out.println(b); after the recursive method why is it still being read, isn't it after the method so it won't be reached?

Comment: @user3383134 I see your edited question. I will change my answer to show you why it prints 1 after 0.

Comment: After the first return statement, why did the value of b that has -1 turn 0?

Comment: @user3383134 Because when b is -1 in your program you checked `if(b < 0) return` So since -1 is less than zero it didn't finish the code in the method and it went back to the previous method to finish working.

Comment: Oh. how about this piece of code, after it returns why does it still increase the  value of b?
public static void a(int b){
if(b<0)
    return;
System.out.println(b);
a(b-1);
System.out.println(b + " is done");
}

Comment: it doesn't increase the value of b. at one point the value of b is zero. In a side project the program is asked to run `a(0-1)` which does nothing because you told it not to. Then it carries on with what it was doing at 0 and prints "0 is done"

Comment: no, not that. but in the output the value of b is increasing. here: "0 is done", "1 is done", "2 is done", ...., "10 is done" Why is that so?

Comment: Also not increasing. When b is 1 it stops for a moment to carry out a(0) and a(0) stops for a moment to carry out a(-1). a(-1) does nothing as its told not to. so then a(0) goes back to what it was doing and prints 0 is done. Then a(1) goes back to what it was doing and prints 1 is done. etc. You're interrupting 1 to do a side-job of 0 and interrupting 0 to do a side job of -1 etc. and then it back tracks. When its done with the side job it goes back to the previous task that was interrupted.

Answer (score 3):

Well you have `a(b+1)` that means there is no end condition for this case which means StackOverflow. as pointed out in the comment, it is stuck between 0 and 1

Comment: While this does cause a StackOverflowError it's not because b+1 goes to infinity. It gets stuck in an infinite recursive loop between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

If b is less than 0, the execution of the method stops. The Code below the return statement will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

The return in this case just finishes the current function/method call, popping things out of the stack and going back up to the previous method call. In other words, that's just your (incomplete) base case. Unless you add a termination condition for the case where `b` increases, the current base case won't be enough to say stop all recursion and you'll get a SO exception.

Answer (score 0):

A stack overflow. The call to `a(b+1)` every time means there will never be a point where the original function can return, or the call to `a(b+1)`, or the call to `a(b+1+1)` and so on.